# Como puedo hacer que la variable guardada en csv lo busque en un buscador de input

Tags: python-3.x

Quiero que el archivo guardado a recopilar este código de csv:

```
guardado = "libro1.py"
with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow([libro_nombre.cget('text')])
    csvwriter.writerow([libro_editorial.cget('text')])
    csvwriter.writerow([libro_autor.cget('text')])
    csvwriter.writerow([libro_paginas.cget('text')])
```

Sea guardado en el archivo python, de una forma que pueda importarlo para el siguiente código:

```
def autor():
  buscadorautor = input("¿Que autor buscas? \n")
  if buscadorautor == "mario kasnet":
```

Claro que en vez de "mario kasnet", iría la variable que se genero por el código csv, es decir esto:

[image: Código guardado a imprimir el csv]

Así al momento de poner en el input de buscadorautor y poner el autor de la variable, me imprima todo el contenido de libro, editorial, autor y números de paginas. Algo así.

¿Qué autor buscas?.
Mario
Me imprima
Libro: LimaLimon
Editorial: Librio
Autor: Mario
Paginas: 132

El código es el siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

biblioteca = tk.Tk()
biblioteca.config(width=300, height=270)
biblioteca.title("Biblioteca")
texto_principal = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Colocar Nuevo Libro")
texto_principal.place(x=70, y=20)

texto = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de libro: ")
texto.place(x=10, y=50)
entry = ttk.Entry()
entry.place(x=140, y=50)
texto1 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de editorial: ")
texto1.place(x=10, y=80)
entry1 = ttk.Entry()
entry1.place(x=140, y=80)
texto2 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre del autor: ")
texto2.place(x=10, y=110)
entry2 = ttk.Entry()
entry2.place(x=140, y=110)
texto3 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Número de paginas: ")
texto3.place(x=10, y=140)
entry3 = ttk.Entry()
entry3.place(x=140, y=140)

def libro():
    libro_nombre = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Libro: " + entry.get())
    libro_nombre.place(x=120, y=200)
    libro_editorial = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Editorial: " + entry1.get())
    libro_editorial.place(x=120, y=215)
    libro_autor = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Autor: " + entry2.get())
    libro_autor.place(x=120, y=230)
    libro_paginas = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nº de Paginas: " + entry3.get())
    libro_paginas.place(x=120, y=245)
    

    guardado = "libro1.py"
    with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_nombre.cget('text')])
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_editorial.cget('text')])
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_autor.cget('text')])
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_paginas.cget('text')])

boton = tk.Button(biblioteca, text = "Guardar", command = libro)
boton.place(x=140, y=170)

biblioteca.mainloop()
```

Comment: no entendi absolutamente nada de lo que esperas que haga tu codigo. podrias redactarlo distinto? parece algo sencillo de resolver pero no me queda claro que deberia hacer el codigo.

Comment: voy a redactarlo distinto.

Answer (score 1):

Ahora comprendo un poco mas lo que esperas del codigo, pero aun asi pareciera que te confundiste mientras lo escribias, talvez puedas revisarlo denuevo.

---

Hasta donde entendi, tu quieres hacer una busqueda de datos en un archivo txt usando de filtro un texto proveniente de tu interfaz grafica que corresponde al autor del libro.

## SOLUCION

### **ESTRUCTURANDO EL TXT**

Para lograr encontrar la informacion de manera mas facil en el txt yo haria lo siguiente:

Reestructurar la informacion que se envia al archivo txt en 4 columnas por libro

estructurar la informacion del archivo txt en 4 columnas correspondientes a libro, editorial y autor, y cada fila seria un registro de cada libro. lo cual se representaria de la siguiente manera

[image: nueva estructura del txt]

Para lograr que tu codigo genere un txt con esa estructura, se debe modificar la string que entregas al metodo writerow()
Esta string debera tener la informacion ordenada de la misma forma que aparecera en el archivo txt.
Debido a que cada writerow() escribe una linea completa y salta a la linea siguiente tras terminar de escribir, solo se requerira llamar solo una vez el metodo cada vez que deseas almacenar informacion de un libro nuevo.

Los objetos entregados al metodo quedarian de la siguiente manera.

```
csvwriter.writerow([libro_nombre.cget('text')  ,
                   libro_editorial.cget('text'),
                   libro_autor.cget('text')    ,
                   libro_paginas.cget('text')]   )
```

Esta llamada del metodo `writerow()` reemplazaria a las sentencias que usas para escribir en el txt, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
    with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_nombre.cget('text')  ,
                           libro_editorial.cget('text'),
                           libro_autor.cget('text')    ,
                           libro_paginas.cget('text')]   )
```

Con solo esta linea de codigo, se resuelve el problema de estructura compleja de tu informacion en el archivo txt.
Pero usare otras variables para mantener el codigo mas ordenado, estas variables contendran la informacion que viene de cada entry:

```
    nombre_libro    = entry.get()
    editorial_libro = entry1.get()
    autor_libro     = entry2.get()
    paginas_libro   = entry3.get()
```

Estas variables las utilizare en el codigo anterior, de escritura de linea en el archivo txt, para que sea mas ordenado.
Reemplazando cada uno queda de la siguiente manera:

```
    with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow([nombre_libro   ,
                           editorial_libro ,
                           autor_libro     ,
                           paginas_libro   ]   )
```

Finalmente para que sea mas facil de leer el codigo y se pueda relacionar la estructura de la lista con el del txt, usare una variable que reciba los datos de libro y se entregue como objeto al metodo `writerow()`

```
    with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        informacion_libro = [nombre_libro,editorial_libro,autor_libro,paginas_libro] 
        csvwriter.writerow( informacion_libro )
```

### **BUSCANDO AL AUTOR**

Lo siguiente es encontrar el libro en base al autor.
Para esto te sugiero la solucion con paquete y sin paquete
Solucion sin paquete
La solucion sin paquete consiste en acceder a la informacion del archivo txt, posterior a su escritura, y almacenarla en una lista de python, desde el cual encontraras tu informacion usando un for que recorrera la lista compuesta con la informacion de cada libro.

La lista tendra la siguiente estructura, ejemplifico con tus datos actuales:

lista_libros = [ [ LimaLimon,Librio,Mario,132] ,
[Cien Años de Soledad,  Librio, Mario, 214]    ]

Lo cual se generaliza de esta forma:

```
variable_lista_libros = [ [ nombre libro, editorial, autor, paginas] , 

                          [...,  ..., ..., ...] ,

                          [...,  ..., ..., ...] ]
```

Para que la informacion de tu archivo txt llegue a esta lista se usara el siguiente codigo:

**CODIGO DE CARGA DE ARCHIVOS**

```
lista_libros = []              # lista para almacenar la info del archivo
nombre_archivo = "libro1.txt"  # variable con el nombre del archivo txt
info_libro = ""                # variable para contener la info de un libro

archivo_txt = open( nombre_archivo, "r")        # se abre el archivo txt
for libro in archivo_txt.readline():            # se accede a cada linea del archivo por iteracion
       info_libro = libro.strip().split(",")    # se elimina el caracter "\n" y se separarn los datos en base a las comas
       lista_libros.append(info_libro )         # se agrega la info del libro a la lista de los libros

archivo_txt.close()                             # se cierra el archivo txt
```

Una vez la informacion se encuentra en la lista, para encontrar la informacion de un libro en especifico, tu debes recorrerla consultando si coincide tu string con la informacion contenida en la respectiva ubicacion

Si tu estas buscando un autor, entonces el codigo seria:

```
datos_libro = ""
for info_libro in lista_libros:
       if "Mario" == info_libro[2]:
           datos_libro = info_libro
           break
```

Esto `info_libro[2]` corresponde al tercer elemento de los datos de un libro contenida en la lista del libro, el cual representa un autor.

Entonces el codigo de arriba recorre la lista de libros. Consulta en cada lista, conteniendo la informacion del respectivo libro, si la informacion contenida en el tercer elemento coincide con tu string. Si coincide entonces se guardar toda la informacion de esa lista en una variable y se termina el ciclo for, ya que tu busqueda fue exitosa.

Pero a este codigo le falta estar vinculado a tu interfaz grafica, para poder consultar por un autor en especifico, por lo que se debera crear una entry nueva para ingresar el nombre del autor en consulta.
La entry se configura como:

**CONFIGURACION DE ENTRY DE AUTOR BUSCADO**

```
Entry_autor_buscado = ttk.Entry()
Entry_autor_buscado .place(x=160, y=140)
```

Esta entry tendra que consultarse antes de realizar la busqueda de la informacion del libro con ese autor, por lo que el codigo anterior se complementa quedando en el siguiente:

**CODIGO DE BUSQUEDA DE AUTOR EN LISTA DE DATOS DE LIBROS**

```
autor_consultado = Entry_autor_buscado.get()
datos_libro = ""
for info_libro in lista_libros:
       if autor_consultado  == info_libro[2]:
           datos_libro = info_libro
           break
```

De esta forma, el codigo anterior queda GENERALIZADO para la busqueda de cualquier string de la celda de autor en la lista de datos de libros.

Finalmente, podrias presentar la informacion del libro con un Label en tkinter.
Para esto, tendrias que agregar dos Label desde el comienzo y modificar su contenido del segundo, una vez exitosa la busqueda.
La configuracion de ambas Label seria el siguiente

**CONFIGURACION DE LABEL DE MOSTRAR DATOS LIBRO**

```
Label_info_libro = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Informacion del libro: ")
Label_info_libro .place(x= 200, y= 200)

Label_mostrar_info_libro = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Resultado ")
Label_mostrar_info_libro .place(x= 200, y= 220)
```

La actualizacion del texto de la segunda label, para mostrar el contenido, seria el siguiente.

**SENTENCIA PARA ACTUALIZAR LABEL DE INFO DEL LIBRO**

```
Label_info_libro["text"] = datos_libro
```

Para realizar la busqueda se debera crear un boton nuevo al cual asociar una funcion que ejecutara todo el codigo anteriormente tratado: cargar datos, buscar datos y actualizar informacion.
Cada una de estas acciones seran separadas en funciones distintas para mantener el codigo prolijo.
Las funciones se llamaran Cargar_datos, Buscar_datos y mostrar datos.

El boton nuevo para ejecutar la busqueda de la informacion se configura de la siguiente manera.

**CONFIGURACION DE BOTON DE BUSCAR LIBRO**

```
boton_buscar_libro = tk.Button(biblioteca, text = "Buscar Libro", command = Buscar_autor)
boton_buscar_libro.place(x=100, y=150)
```

Cada una de las acciones anteriores tendra una funcion para si misma.
Por lo que se debera crear una funcion para cada una, quedando de la siguiente manera

**Funcion para cargar txt**

```
def Cargar_txt():
    lista_libros = []              # lista para almacenar la info del archivo
    nombre_archivo = "libro1.txt"  # variable con el nombre del archivo txt

    archivo_txt = open( nombre_archivo, "r")   # se abre el archivo txt
    for fila in archivo_txt.readline():        # se accede a cada linea del 
       if fila != "" and fila != "\n":                                             
           info_libro = fila.strip().split(",") # se elimina el caracter "\n" y se 
                                 #separarn los datos en base a las comas
           lista_libros.append(info_libro )     # se agrega la info del libro a la  #lista de los libros
    archivo.Seek(0)
    archivo_txt.close() 
    return lista_libros
```

**Funcion para buscar autor**

La funcion de `Buscar_autor()` debera llamar a `Cargar_datos()` cada vez que se ejecute y recibira de esta la lista con los datos de los libros y ademas consultara el entry de autor para finalmente buscar y mostrar los datos.

```
def Buscar_autor():
# cargar datos de los libros
    lista_libros = Cargar_txt()
# realizar busqueda del libro
    datos_libro = ""
    autor_consultado = Entry_autor_buscado.get()
    for info_libro in lista_libros:
        if autor_consultado  == info_libro[2]:
           Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = " ".join( info_libro )
           break
        else:
           Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = "el autor no esta presente"
# mostrar los datos del libro en el label
```

Todo lo anterior combinado en el codigo final seria:

---

**CODIGO FINAL**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

biblioteca = tk.Tk()
biblioteca.config(width=300, height=270)
biblioteca.title("Biblioteca")
texto_principal = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Colocar Nuevo Libro")
texto_principal.place(x=70, y=20)

texto = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de libro: ")
texto.place(x=10, y=50)
entry = ttk.Entry()
entry.place(x=140, y=50)
texto1 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de editorial: ")
texto1.place(x=10, y=80)
entry1 = ttk.Entry()
entry1.place(x=140, y=80)
texto2 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre del autor: ")
texto2.place(x=10, y=110)
entry2 = ttk.Entry()
entry2.place(x=140, y=110)
texto3 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Número de paginas: ")
texto3.place(x=10, y=140)
entry3 = ttk.Entry()
entry3.place(x=140, y=140)
####################### ETIQUETAS NUEVAS ######################
Label_info_libro = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Informacion del libro: ")
Label_info_libro .place(x= 10, y= 200)
Label_mostrar_info_libro = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Resultado ")
Label_mostrar_info_libro.place(x= 10, y= 220)
######################## ETIQUETAS NUEVAS ######################

def libro():
    libro_nombre = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Libro: " + entry.get())
    libro_nombre.place(x=120, y=200)
    libro_editorial = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Editorial: " + entry1.get())
    libro_editorial.place(x=120, y=215)
    libro_autor = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Autor: " + entry2.get())
    libro_autor.place(x=120, y=230)
    libro_paginas = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nº de Paginas: " + entry3.get())
    libro_paginas.place(x=120, y=245)
    
###################### SENTENCIAS MEJORADAS #######################
    nombre_libro    = entry.get()
    editorial_libro = entry1.get()
    autor_libro     = entry2.get()
    paginas_libro   = entry3.get()

    guardado = "libro1.txt"
    with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        informacion_libro = [nombre_libro,editorial_libro,autor_libro,paginas_libro] 
        csvwriter.writerow( informacion_libro )
##################### SENTENCIAS MEJORADAS #########################

##################### FUNCIONES NUEVAS ###############################

def Cargar_txt():
    lista_libros = []              # lista para almacenar la info del archivo
    nombre_archivo = "libro1.txt"  # variable con el nombre del archivo txt

    archivo_txt = open( nombre_archivo, "r")        # se abre el archivo txt
    # print(archivo_txt)
    # print("readlines:",archivo_txt.readlines())
    for fila in archivo_txt.readlines():            # se accede a cada linea del  archivo por iteracion
        # print("iterador for:",libro)                  
        if fila != "\n" and fila != "":               
            fila = fila.strip().split(",")    # se elimina el caracter "\n" y se  separarn los datos en base a las comas
            # print("info libro:",info_libro)
            lista_libros.append(fila )         # se agrega la info del libro a la lista de los libros
            # print("lista libros:",lista_libros)                                 
    archivo_txt.seek(0)                          # devuelve el cursor del texto al inicio del archivo
    # print(lista_libros)
    archivo_txt.close() 
    return lista_libros


def Buscar_autor():
# cargar datos de los libros
    lista_libros = Cargar_txt()
# realizar busqueda del libro
    datos_libro = ""
    autor_consultado = Entry_autor_buscado.get()
    for info_libro in lista_libros:
        if autor_consultado  == info_libro[2]:
           Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = " ".join( info_libro )
           break
        else:
           Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = "el autor no esta presente"
# mostrar los datos del libro en el label


###########################  FUNCIONES NUEVAS  ########################

boton = tk.Button(biblioteca, text = "Guardar", command = libro)
boton.place(x=140, y=170)

####################### BOTON NUEVO #################################
boton_buscar_libro = tk.Button(biblioteca, text = "Buscar Libro", command = Buscar_autor)
boton_buscar_libro.place(x=200, y=170)
############################ BOTON NUEVO ############################

############################ ENTRY DE AUTOR #########################
Entry_autor_buscado = ttk.Entry()
Entry_autor_buscado .place(x=10, y=170)
############################ ENTRY DE AUTOR #########################

biblioteca.mainloop()
```

La interfaz grafica queda de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta enlace al archivo del codigo para que lo ejecutes y no ocurran errores al copiar y pegar

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6xEqzt_k4Q_PqViPYRW9dXNX7UXAZfc/view?usp=sharing

DEMOSTRACION DE RESULTADO EXITOSO

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es una respuesta larga pero es con el fin de justificar y explicar detalladamente cada parte del codigo y puedas posteriormente modificarlo a conveniencia.
Debido a que hay muchas funciones, widgets y variables relacionadas entre si es muy probable errores, por lo cual te dejo las siguientes precauciones sobre algunas variables y uso de metodos

**Precauciones**

1. El archivo txt con los datos de los libros debe ubicarse en la misma
   carpeta que tu codigo, de otra forma arrojara error.
2. El archivo txt solo se abrira si es que se la string que contiene su
   nombre es identica al nombre del archivo, de otra forma arrojara
   error.
3. Es probable que salten errores o no encuentre coincidencia si a los
   entry ingresas datos inexactos o con caracteres especiales como
   comas puntos.
4. Los botones, labels y funciones llamadas tienen una alta
   probabilidad de estar relacionadas a un error por llamarlas con un
   nombre distinto a lo largo del codigo.

**Sugerencias**

1. Te recomiendo aprender programacion orientada a objetos (POO) antes
   de avanzar en este proyecto.
2. Te recomiendo renombrar cada una de las variables que contienen
   algun widget de tkinter con un nombre mas especifico y descriptivo
   para prevenir errores e incoherencias y perdidas de tiempo por no
   recordar que contenia cada una.
3. Si te arroja algun error el codigo que adjunte, porfavor,
   recuerda incluir el mensaje de error que muestra la consola.

Eso es todo. Estare atento a tus dudas o errores de codigo que surjan.

Comment: me sale esto en el python idle SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single stateme y me marca en rojo el siguiente código import tkinter as tk, cuando lo abro en block de notas me aparece la pantalla en negro pero se cierra rapido.

Comment: pero cuando abro mi código con el mismo  import tkinter as tk, si me recopila normal.

Comment: es extraño, copie y pegue el codigo lo ejecute y funciono sin error. te dejo una foto de como qeuda la interfaz. dime si te funciona. cambie ciertas cosas al  codigo que tenia error de identacion

Comment: Si me recopilo el archivo, pero al momento de darle buscar libro me sale esto     return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\prueba7.py", line 82, in Buscar_autor
    if "Mario" == info_libro[2]:
IndexError: list index out of range. Ya convertir la salida del archivo de python a texto para que este igual a tu código pero no funciono.

Comment: Como haría para que en vez de  if "Mario" == info_libro[2]:, pueda poner input() y pueda tipear el nombre del autor, para buscar el autor en el archivo texto guardado por el csv. O pueda usar la misma caja de texto de autor, para buscar el autor en el archivo de texto.

Comment: Hola, corregi el codigo. el buscar distintos autores estaba en el codigo que explique pero lo copie mal en el codigo final. corregi distintos errores y ahora funciona, deje una imagen demostrando que si da el resultado. descargalo desde mi drive para que no surjan errores por copiar y pegar. cuentame como te va. Recuerda que el txt debe tener nombre "libro1.txt" y que debe estar en tu misma carpeta del programa

Comment: si funciona mucha gracias, no sabía como hacerlo. Te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Que bueno,denada

Comment: una pregunta, cuando pongo en el buscador el autor, me sale el libro cien años de soledad con un resultado así {cien años de soledad}, pero cuando pongo limalimon, me salen sin {}, hay alguna forma de poner el nombre del libro con espacio sin que te salga {}.

Comment: Claro, todo lo que se muestra depende de lo que se encuentra contenido en el archivo txt. talvez ingresaste esos caracteres al archivo txt cuando guardaste la info del libro. tan solo abre el archivo txt y eliminalos, o elimina el archivo y vuelve a ingresar la info sin esos caracteres.

Comment: no me aparece en el archivo texto que se guarda, me aparece así cien años de soledad, librio, mario, 122, sin { }, esto solo aparece cuando escribo un libro con espacio como cien años de soledad, pero cuando pongo limalimon no me aparece.

Comment: Hola. los parentesis se agregan al momento de cambiar el atributo text de la etiqueta al asignar Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = datos_libro. Estos parentesis se evitan al reemplazar esa linea por la siguiente:  Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = " ".join( autor_consultado). Ya lo probe y funciona. actualizo la respuesta y el archivo tambien.

Comment: si funciona muchas gracias, te lo agradezco mucho. Una última cosa por favor, como hago para que la búsqueda que aparece así cien años de soledad, librio, ,mario, 422, me aparezca así cuando doy clic en el botón de búsqueda; 
Libro: cien años de soledad
Editorial: librio(pero esto sigue en el siguiente reglón de abajo)
Autor: mario(pero esto sigue en el siguiente reglón de abajo)
Paginas: 422(pero esto sigue en el siguiente reglón de abajo)

Comment: para ese resultado, simplemente debes reemplazar la linea que te mencione anteriormente por Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = "\n".join( autor_consultado)

Comment: CORRECION  para ese resultado, simplemente debes reemplazar la linea que te mencione anteriormente por             'resumen = "Libro: {}\nEditorial: {}\nAutor: {}\nPaginas: {}".format( *autor_consultado)
            Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = resumen'

Comment: cuando pongo el código me sale en resultado de búsqueda lo siguiente Libro: c Editorial:  i Autor: e Paginas:  n.

Comment: CORRECION me equivoque de variable 'resumen = "Libro: {}\nEditorial: {}\nAutor: {}\nPaginas: {}".format( *info_libro) Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = resumen'

Comment: si me funciono el código como lo mencione, pero el segundo reglón de Editorial, aparece más a la derecha que el primer reglón y lo mismo con el tercer y último reglón. No se puede hacer algo para que aparezca todo en un mismo lado sin que se valla mucho a la derecha.

Comment: reemplaza esta linea. Label_mostrar_info_libro = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Resultado ")  por esta Label_mostrar_info_libro = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Resultado ", anchor = "w")

Comment: La segunda, tercera y cuarto reglón se va a la derecha igual.

Comment: no se me ocurre nada corto de implementar. talvez podrias agregar 4 labels una encima de otra y darle los datos por separado.

Comment: como seria para poner 4 labels en el código con libro, editorial, autor y paginas ???

Comment: te recomendaria intentar aprender aresolver tus dudas antes de usar a los otros. todo lo que me consultas se hace muy facil y la informacion esta disponible. veo que no has nisiquiera intentado aprender la libreria tkinter y llevas varias preguntas montando el codigo por separado.